# Efficiently determining if large sorted numpy array has only unique values

Tags: python, arrays, sorting, numpy, unique

I have a very large numpy array and I want to sort it and test if it is unique.

I'm aware of the function `numpy.unique` but it sorts the array another time to achieve it.

The reason I need the array sorted *a priori* is because the returned keys from the `argsort` function will be used to reorder another array.

I'm looking for a way to do both (`argsort` and unique test) without the need to sort the array again.

**Example code:**

```
import numpy as np
import numpy.random

# generating random arrays with 2 ^ 27 columns (it can grow even bigger!)
slices = np.random.random_integers(2 ** 32, size = 2 ** 27)
values = np.random.random_integers(2 ** 32, size = 2 ** 27)

# get an array of keys to sort slices AND values
# this operation takes a long time
sorted_slices = slices.argsort()

# sort both arrays
# it would be nice to make this operation in place
slices = slices[sorted_slices]
values = values[sorted_slices]

# test 'uniqueness'
# here, the np.unique function sorts the array again
if slices.shape[0] == np.unique(slices).shape[0]:
    print('it is unique!')
else:
    print('not unique!')
```

Both the arrays `slices` and `values` have 1 row and the same (huge) number of columns.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is this just toy example data for us, or are you actually working with 2^27 or more 32-bit ints?

Comment: @StefanPochmann I'm actually working with this number of integers as this is for a scientific application.

Comment: Then you can pretty much replace your uniqueness check with `False` :-). Very fast, and wrong only about once in 10^500000 attempts, i.e., practically never.

Comment: @StefanPochmann. Not exactly. In my example I'm using random numbers for easier understanding, but in the real application they are generated by other, exact, methods which will easily make duplicates.

Comment: Did you mean to say those methods will easily **avoid** duplicates? Because if they make duplicates more likely, then it's even less likely that the simple `False` is wrong.

Comment: @StefanPochmann, sorry, my bad. They will easily **avoid** duplicates.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can check whether there are two or more equal values next to each other (non-unique values in a sorted array) by comparing their difference to `0`

```
numpy.any(numpy.diff(slices) == 0)
```

Be aware though that numpy will create two intermediate arrays: one with the difference values, one with boolean values.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't knew the function ```numpy.diff```. I made it even better (I guess) by using ```numpy.diff(slices).all()```, creating only one intermediate array.

Answer (score 3):

Here's an approach making use of [`slicing`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#basic-slicing-and-indexing) and instead of actual differentiation, we can just compare each element against the previous one without actually computing the differentiation value, like so -

```
~((slices[1:] == slices[:-1]).any())
```

Runtime test -

```
In [54]: slices = np.sort(np.random.randint(0,100000000,(10000000)))

# @Nils Werner's soln
In [55]: %timeit ~np.any(np.diff(slices) == 0)
100 loops, best of 3: 18.5 ms per loop

# @Marco's suggestion in comments
In [56]: %timeit np.diff(slices).all()
10 loops, best of 3: 20.6 ms per loop

# Proposed soln in this post
In [57]: %timeit ~((slices[1:] == slices[:-1]).any())
100 loops, best of 3: 6.12 ms per loop
```

Comment: Nice, I was also thinking about slicing, but too quickly dismissed the idea :-)